# Postgres performance issues

Tags: performance, postgresql

We are running Postgres 9.1.3 and we have recently started to run into major performance problems on one of our servers.

Our queries ran fine for a while, but as of August 1st, they have slowed down dramatically. It would appear that most of the problematic queries are Select queries (queries with count(*) are especially bad), but in general, the database is just running really slow.

We ran [this](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Server_Configuration) query on the server and these were the changes that we have made to the default config file (Note: The server ran fine with these changes before, so, they likely don't matter much) :

```
       name            |                                                current_setting
---------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
version                   | PostgreSQL 9.1.2 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by  gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-51), 64-bit
autovacuum                | off
bgwriter_delay            | 20ms
checkpoint_segments       | 6
checkpoint_warning        | 0
client_encoding           | UTF8
default_statistics_target | 1000
effective_cache_size      | 4778MB
effective_io_concurrency  | 2
fsync                     | off
full_page_writes          | off
lc_collate                | en_US.UTF-8
lc_ctype                  | en_US.UTF-8
listen_addresses          | *
maintenance_work_mem      | 1GB
max_connections           | 100
max_stack_depth           | 2MB
port                      | 5432
random_page_cost          | 2
server_encoding           | UTF8
shared_buffers            | 1792MB
synchronous_commit        | off
temp_buffers              | 16MB
TimeZone                  | US/Eastern
wal_buffers               | 16MB
wal_level                 | minimal
wal_writer_delay          | 10ms
work_mem                  | 16MB
(28 rows)

Time: 210.231 ms
```

Normally, when problems like this arise, the first thing people recommend is vacuuming and we have tried that. We vacuum analyzed most of the database, but it didn't help.

We used `Explain` on some of our queries and noticed that Postgres was resorting to sequential scans even though the tables had indexes.

We turned sequential scan off to force the query planner into using indexes, but that did not help either.

We then tried out [this](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Show_database_bloat) query to see if we had a lot of unused diskspace that Postgres was going through in order to find what it is looking for. Unfortunately, while some of our tables did have a bit of bulk, it did not seem significant enough to slow down overall system performance.

We think the slowdown might be I/O related, but we can't figure out the specifics. Is Postgres just being silly and if so, what part of it? Is there something wrong with the VM, or perhaps something wrong with the physical hardware itself?

Do you guys have any other suggestions for things that we can try or check out?

EDIT:

I am so sorry for not updating this sooner. I got caught up in other things.

On this particular machine, our performance greatly improved by making one small modification to the Virtual Machine's settings.

There is a setting that deals with IO caching. It was originally set to to ON. We figured that constantly caching things was slowing things down and we were right. We turned it OFF, and things improved drastically.

Interestingly enough most of our other servers already had this setting turned off.

There are other issues, and I am sure we will take a lot of your suggestions, so, thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: Are any of these troublesome queries selecting from a single table? If so, can you drop indexes, then create them again as a test? (There's nothing special about a single table, except that it's simpler to test.)

Comment: Is this a dedicated database server? How much RAM installed?

Comment: @Catcall The server is not a dedicated server. It runs the front and back end of our application. It is a virtual image (on KVM) with 8GB of Ram, but we aren't being Ram starved, we are being IO starved. The IO usage often goes to 100% during queries.

I don't think the recreating of indexes has made much difference, but I will have to get back to you on that.

Comment: Are you sure it's postgres that's using all the resources and not something else? Maybe a backup or something?

Comment: Thanks for showing your version and config right off the cuff. Any chance of an `explain analyze` or two, showing how the row estimates differed from the reality? Does a database-wide `VACUUM ANALYZE` help?

Comment: The best way to avoid being disk bound is to have enough RAM to cache the data.  With more RAM, you do less IO.

Comment: WRT the server configuration, I don't know if this might be of any use: https://github.com/impredicative/pgtune

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's difficult to be sure, but I think you are right to be suspicious of I/O issues. What can happen is that as tables get larger or connections are increased then cache hits start to fall. That increases I/o demands and slows everything down. Meanwhile, more queries arrive, making the problem worse. The situation is complicated for you because virtual disks don't necessarily behave the same as physical ones.

Firstly you will need to measure actual activity on the VM (through vmstat or iostat perhaps). Secondly, do the same on the real hardware. Finally, run some standard disk bandwidth tools on both (in particular random read/write mixes). Now you'll be able to say how much of your available I/o is being used.

As for query plans, without the schema details and explain analyse output no-one can say.

You will find the postgresql.org mailing list useful even if just for the archives. Also, the book linked below is excellent.

http://www.packtpub.com/postgresql-90-high-performance/book

Answer (score 15):

Your biggest problem is this line:

```
autovacuum                | off
```

Turning it on won't immediately cure the problem, but it should keep things from eroding further.  There are almost no cases where it is a good idea to turn this off.  The main exception is a big bulk load followed by an explicit VACUUM FREEZE ANALYZE, after which autovacuum should be turned back on.  With autovacuum off, you will see performance degrade, just as you have.  Once the database has gotten into such bad shape, it requires more aggressive maintenance than autovacuum can provide to recover.

```
checkpoint_segments       | 6
```

Increasing this will help data modifications, but won't do much to improve the speed of `SELECT` statements.

```
fsync                     | off
full_page_writes          | off
```

These settings tell PostgreSQL to speed up writes at the expense of persistence.  If your hardware or OS (or VM) crashes or is abruptly killed, your database will be corrupted and your best bet will be to restore from your last known good backup.  (Of course, since hardware can fail at any time, if you care about losing the data, you have a good backup strategy in place.)

```
maintenance_work_mem      | 1GB
```

This is too high for an 8GB VM.  You can always boost it on a single connection before running some heavy maintenance on that connection.

```
wal_writer_delay          | 10ms
```

Even seasoned experts have trouble adjusting this to something that gets better performance than the default.  It is almost always best left alone.

Your best bet at this point is to use pg_dumpall to dump your database cluster to some other medium, start with a fresh initdb, and restore.  As a database superuser, run `VACUUM FREEZE ANALYZE` (the `FREEZE` is not generally recommended except after a bulk load like that), and run with autovacuum turned on.

I highly recommend that you get a copy of Greg Smith's "PostgreSQL 9.0 High Performance" book, and read it carefully.  (Full disclosure, I was one of the technical reviewers for the book, but get no money from sales.)  One of the first things he recommends is getting benchmark numbers on the speed of your RAM and disk before you even install PostgreSQL -- that way you know what you're dealing with.

Comment: We don't use fsync because of the origin of our data. Most of the data in our database is imported from other databases on a daily basis. If something goes wrong, we can re import it if necessary. We also have our own backup system setup.


We turned auto vacuum off because if it kicks in while doing our bulk loads, it slows things down a lot. We could turn it off before we do the loading and calculating, but given how most of the DB work is the loading of data, then selecting of said data, it is fine. We vacuum every night anyway.
 
Thanks a lot though, I will look into that book. :P

Comment: OK, so it *is* OK if the entire database cluster is lost on OS crash -- that's certainly not unheard of. Turning off `autovacuum` for a bulk load is sane, as is a nightly `VACUUM` (preferably `VACUUM ANALYZE` or `VACUUM FREEZE ANALYZE` run against the entire database under a superuser role). It really *is* a good idea to turn autovacuum back on after the bulk load and subsequent `VACUUM`, because otherwise someone could easily do a frequent update to some small control table or create and drop a lot of temporary tables or do any number of things which could cause problems.

Answer (score 2):

> (queries with count(*) are especially bad),

You should look into [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html)

Otherwise, we have no idea without seeing your relevant schema and your queries.

Comment: Well, I can't really share much (it's a bit hush, hush), but it is not so much that queries are slow, more so that the whole system grinds to a halt when something is running.

Answer (score 0):

I would turn on auto vacuum as well.  There are a few variables you can set that control how much the vacuum will interfere.  With the amount of RAM you have you should have your shared buffers set between 2048MB - 3276MB.  If you have a lot of extra RAM that your system doesn't seem to be using that you don't need elsewhere you should probably set it closer to the higher end.  Also you may want to look at your max segment size with sysctl.  Your maintenance_work_mem is really high, but if you are doing mostly maintenance then I suppose it isn't as bad as I first thought.