# Correct index's on simple table

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have a table in PostgreSQL 9.1:

```
_id           | integer  | not null default nextval('"01f9073e-e6b8-46bf-882f-9a4cd0a69a66__id_seq"'::regclass)
_full_text    | tsvector |
tlRecordID    | text     |
tlPDM         | text     |
tlPayDateTime | text     |
tlExpDateTime | text     |
Indexes:
    "01f9073e-e6b8-46bf-882f-9a4cd0a69a66_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (_id)
    "01f9073e-e6b8-46bf-882f-9a4cd0a69a66_tlRecordID_idx" UNIQUE, btree ("tlRecordID")
    "01f9073e-e6b8-46bf-882f-9a4cd0a_tlPayDateTime_tlExpDateTime_idx" btree ("tlPayDateTime", "tlExpDateTime")
```

There's ~35 mio. rows.

Calling a simple:

```
SELECT MAX("tlRecordID"::integer) AS max_id FROM "01f9073e-e6b8-46bf-882f-9a4cd0a69a66";
```

Does take very long time. Also, more advanced queries such as:

```
FROM "01f9073e-e6b8-46bf-882f-9a4cd0a69a66"
WHERE "tlPayDateTime" != 'None' AND "tlExpDateTime" != 'None' AND
NOW() BETWEEN "tlPayDateTime"::timestamp AND "tlExpDateTime"::timestamp GROUP BY "tlPDM"
```

times out very often etc.

Can anyone help to optimize the database? Is 35 mio. rows a problem or?

Comment: this will maybe help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11940515/postgres-performance-issues

Comment: ...You're shooting yourself in the foot, using a character-based type to store date/time values (that `'None'` should probably be a null).  Also, please read [this blog post](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) for problems relating to using `BETWEEN` with timestamps (the post is specifically about SQL Server, but the logic applies to all measurement/non-integral types)

Comment: Yes, it's those data conversions that are the problem. Using the right datatype is a prerequisite for system performance.

Comment: I'll try with correct datatypes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate to come in here with so many critiques, but I think that troubleshooting this as you have put it will be very very hard.  You have a significant of data type errors which will introduce subtle bugs and performance issues, and naming tables after GUIDs is not a general road to maintainability.

1. You need to move your datetime fields to timestamp or timestamptz types depending on what you want.  You will not get good performance with these as text fields.  Use NULL instead of 'None'
2. For your max id selection, look at the query plans.  We can't provide any feedback there.  Ideally use VERBOSE and tell it to show buffer usage as well.
3. You don't need the regclass cast.  Drop it.